# Parse an SQL statement split in conditions in java

Tags: java, sql, parsing

I want to retrieve an SQL statement from Oracle DB using Java program. Once the SQL statement is retrieved I want to chunk the different where conditions into separate blocks and store it in a Lists.

Is this possible? any references on how to do this would be helpful.

Ex:- Select * from ABC where abc.emplid =1234 and abc.deptid=456;

Now I want the java program to split the two where conditions and store it in a list so that I can use this list data later on for some comparison.

Thanks.

Comment: “Is this possible?”, yes it is but why should we do it?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your result is saved in `List<Employee> employees` . We will save the Employee id  emplid =1234 in one list and deptid=456 in other using Streams and lambdas as

`List<Employee> employeesSortedByEmplId = employees.stream()
    .filter(employee -> p.getEmplId() == 1234).collect(Collectors.toList());`  and 
`List<Employee> employeesSortedByDeptId = employees.stream()
    .filter(employee -> p.getDeptId() == 456).collect(Collectors.toList());`